# Registry not set using Visual Studio 2017 Installer Project

Tags: visual-studio-2017, registry, installation

I create a visual studio installer project on visual studio 2017 for word add-in.
The registry is not set when installing it. What do I do wrong during the process?

I have a MyWordAddIn solution which when running through visual studio correctly open Word 2016 and launch the add-in. I went to the HKEY_CURRENT_USER/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Office/Word/Addins/ and find the myAddIn folder which has been created by visual studio during the debug run.
I now no that I must add 3 string value :

- Manifest : file:///[the local directory]/MyWordAddIn.vsto|vstolocal
- Description : "MyWordAddInName"
- FriendlyName : "My word Add-In name"

  and 1 binary value :
- LoadBehavior : 0x00000003

Back to My Installer Project MyWordAddInSetup :
right click on it > view > File System :
In the Application Folder I added the Assembly used by my project, the primary output, the manifest and the MyWordAddIn.vsto file.

[image]

right click on MyWordAddInSetup > view > Launch Conditions :
set the right .NET FrameWork (4.7.2)

right click on MyWordAddInSetup > view > Registry :
In the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE I created the following key tree :
SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Office/Word/Addins/MyWordAddIns

Then, I added three string value in MyWordAddIns :

- Manifest : file:///[INSTALLDIR]/MyWordAddIn.vsto|vstolocal
- Description : "MyWordAddInName"
- FriendlyName : "My word Add-In name"

  and 1 binary value :
- LoadBehavior : 0x00000003

[image: Preview of the registry tab]

When Installing my MyWordAddIns, the Assembly, dll, manifest and vsto file are well created inside the chosen folder.
But the local registry is not set with the value I wanted.

If I create it myself then the add-In is correctly added in Word 2016.

I tried to create a simple key 'Test' in the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE in the Registry tab of my MyWordAddIns installer. And even that, the 'Test' folder does not appear in the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE registry of my machine.

If I set those registry valuenot in the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE but in the HKEY_CURRENT_USER it well create the values.

Any solution to corectly set the values in the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE ?

Comment: In the last image, it must not be [INSTALLDIR] but [TARGETDIR]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. It was a user mistake.
To have the key values set in the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE you must click on 'Everyon' button during the Installation 
[image]